# CF datefield - calendar icon doesn't trigger date picker while data is loading

Tags: coldfusion, datefield, cfinput

I am using CF input calendar datefield on the very top of a page that renders  a huge dataset from a query. The output from this huge query also has some pretty heavy code for each loop iteration. So, I have a very slow loading page.

The problem is - while the heavy data loads (cfflush is used after cfform), the calendar image button is displayed but it doesn't trigger the datepicker overlay until the entire dataset is loaded.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Probably because the JavaScript triggers onload (i.e. after browser has received and rendered all the HTML). Either make the page load faster, and/or have the large dataset loaded separately (e.g. using iframe or ajax or whatever).

Comment: Or, have the calendar after the cfflush instead of before.